# Questions on the Zakharov-Shabat inverse scattering paper

Tags: waves, scattering, complex-numbers, solitons

I am trying to work through the [Zakharov and Shabat paper on inverse scattering for the nonlinear Schrodinger equation](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Exact-Theory-of-Two-dimensional-Self-focusing-and-Zakharov-Shabat/73ef172d46291e1b2235d4fea6d80078f5e705ef) ([PDF](http://zakharov75.itp.ac.ru/static/local/zve75/zakharov/1972/1972-05-e_034_01_0062.pdf)). I am stuck on section 2.

[Problem 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jau07.jpg). I need to know how to reconstruct $\Phi$ from its discontinuous definition.
I have found the Sokhotskyi formulas which should give
$$\Phi(\zeta) = \frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_{-\infty}^{+ \infty} \frac{\phi (\xi)}{\xi - \zeta} d \xi$$
but this requires $\Phi$ to be analytic in the upper and lower half plane. What I need is some way of extending this to include the poles. The residue of $\Phi$ at each $\zeta = \zeta_k$ is what multiplies each $\frac{1}{\zeta - \zeta_k}$ in the sum. I have no idea why the (1,0) vector is included.

[Problem 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HbKSA.jpg). I dont know how the circled equations came about. I dont really know what to say about this, I just dont know how to get them.

Any help you can give me would be much appreciated.